# Why property default value does not work in free pascal?

Tags: freepascal

I want to have default http error code 500.

I can't override constructor (I've found [some docs about it](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/exception.create.html), but compiler says `There is no method in an ancestor class to be overridden: "constructor HttpError.Create(const AnsiString);`)

I tried to add `Default 500` to Status property definition, but it also does not work (i see 0).

How i can achieve `500` value by default for Status?

```
{$IFDEF FPC}
  {$MODE DELPHI}
{$ENDIF}

program test;

uses
  SysUtils;

Type
  {:Base http exception}
  HttpError = class(Exception)
  private
    FStatus: Integer;
  published
    property Status: Integer Read FStatus Write FStatus Default 500;
  end;

begin
  try
    Raise HttpError.Create('Ooops');
  except
    on e: HttpError do
      WriteLn(e.Status);
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously `Default` does not do what you expect it to.

In fact `Default` is used for something very specific, namely to indicate to the form streaming system that this published (form streamed) property has a default value of (in this case) 500, so that if the value isn't changed away from this, the value doesn't need to be saved with the form data.

Note that - somewhat confusingly - even in a component streaming context, where the `Default` attribute is used, declaring a default value like you do here doesn't actually set the default value of the field - you must do that manually in the constructor.

Finally you only `override` a constructor if it's virtual in the base class, and the constructors of the `Exception` type are not. Just declare it as a normal constructor and call the appropriate ancestor within it with `inherited... Create(...`

Virtual constructors are mostly used for components where construction is done in response to parsing data out of a form file.

Comment: Futhermore, there is no reason for this property to be "published", "public" would do the same - and you might not even need that.